# cannot "grep abc *" in "/lib/systemd/system" on Debian 8 Jessie

Tags: linux, debian

On Debian 8 I cannot do the following command in /lib/systemd/system:

```
root@foo:/lib/systemd/system# grep abc *

grep: invalid option -- '.' Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]... Try 'grep --help' for more information.
```

Why is that?

Comment: Is there a file named `-.` in the directory?

Comment: steeldriver could be right. Is grep maybe an alias `type grep`?

Comment: Yes, right.  I thought ls | sort would show those files at the beginning.  -.slice is shown between sleep and slices.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep -- abc *
```

As steeldriver1 mentionned, on my system there is indeed a file called -.slice in that directory.

This leads to some unexpected behavior since linux treats such symbols as commands.

For example mv - * tab * doesn't auto complete the filename but mv -- '- * tab * does.

I figured it out by reading this page which explains it nicely. http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linuxunix-move-file-starting-with-a-dash/